# Declaring variables in another class - pros and cons

Tags: c#, class, variables

I'm a beginner in C# and am trying to understand the effects of declaring variables in different scopes. Is there any appreciable performance difference between:

**Example 1**

```
class A
{
   static int i;
   static string temp;
}

class B
{
   while(true)
   {
       A.i=10;
       A.temp="Hello";
   }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
class B
{
   int i;
   string temp;
   while(true)
   {
       i=10;
       temp="Hello";
   }
}
```

**Example 3**

```
class A
{
   public int i;
   public string temp;
}

class B
{
A D = new A();
   while(true)
   {
       D.i=10;
       D.temp="Hello";
   }
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't compile actually

Comment: There is no practical performance difference. Just write the code that looks clearest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code snippet shares both variables: they get allocated statically, and all threads would use them in concurrent environments. This is very bad - one should avoid situations like that in production code.

The second and the third code snippets are thread safe. The third snippet groups variables `i` and `temp`; the second snippet does not. In addition, the third snippet needs an extra allocation of an object, and creates an object to be collected upon return (of course it never returns because of the infinite `while (true)` loop, so it does not really matter).

If the two variables do not belong together logically, you should avoid making a class for them. If they do belong together, you should move the code that uses these variables into the class that declares them.

As far as the performance and memory implications go, the third snippet requires an extra chunk of memory compared to the second one, but it is too small to pay attention to. The performance difference will be nearly impossible to detect, so you should not worry about it much: in most cases, it is best to optimize your code for readability.

Comment: *"...statically...one should avoid situations like that in production code."*   That's a very broad statement, don't you think, for this context?

Comment: @MichaelBray Assuming that the class is publicly visible and all its static variables are mutable, the statement is about right. Of course there are situations where a mutable global is justified, but they are so rare and far between that they are hardly worth mentioning. I worked for a company where introducing a mutable global was allowed only with a written permission of the chief architect. In my four years at the company, nobody on our team has requested such a permission.

Comment: My point wasn't the accuracy or justification of your statement.  It was that the OP is obviously new to development and even made a point of it, and you're throwing thread safety and concurrency at him.  It's like Michael Jordan trying to teach my cat to play basketball.  I think this person will forever be put off to static, thinking it's always bad, when it certainly isn't.